# Android: set fixed item on RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView, when I click in the first view it adds another view like in the image, what I want is to set the "add" view which ID is "1" to be fixed in the last position of the recycler instead in the first.
[image]

**My adapter:**

```
public class AddEventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddEventsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

   private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(String name) {
        items.add(name);
        notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        items.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, items.size());
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_event_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setEventNameName(i + "");
        if(position == 0) 
        {
            holder.theLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7F9099"));
            holder.eventName.setText("Add");
        }

    }
    static int i;
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView eventName;
        public RelativeLayout theLayout;




        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            eventName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
            theLayout = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundevent);

            theLayout.setId(++i);

            theLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (getAdapterPosition()>0){
                        removeItem(getAdapterPosition());
                    }else {
                        addItem("");
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        public void setEventNameName(String TheEventName){
            eventName.setText(TheEventName);
        }
    }
}
```

**In the activity:**

```
final AddEventsAdapter AddContainer = new AddEventsAdapter();
    AddEventsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    AddEventsRecycler.setAdapter(AddContainer);
    AddEventsRecycler.setItemViewCacheSize(666);

    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
    itemAnimator.setAddDuration(1000);
    itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(1000);
    AddEventsRecycler.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);

    AddContainer.addItem("");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by creating a custom adapter that allows a footer and a header, here is the project in GitHub: https://github.com/u3breeze/android-RecyclerView-WithHeaderAndFooter

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like:

```
 public void addItem(String name) {
        if (items.size() != 0) {
            removeItem(items.size() - 1);
            items.add(name);
            items.add("Add");
        } else
            items.add("Add");

        notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
    }
```

then id of Add item is `items.size() -1`

**edit:**
Change if in your Holder class with following code:

```
     if(position == items.size() - 1) 
   {      
         holder.theLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7F9099"));
                    holder.eventName.setText("Add");
                }
```

Comment: It crashes when opening the activity

Comment: what is exception message?

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: Now it's behaving extreemly weird, the "add" button remains on the top, and when I click it, the last view gets removed, and it adds two views

Comment: see now what i did and try. Try to write method which when you click on add that first remove "add" item and then add item  which you want in list and then add "add" item again. Maybe this is not best solution but i could work... Maybe you should to consider to add button "add" like fab instead item .

Comment: Still not working, I'm already inflating the view when clicking on a fab, I did thought about setting a static view under the recycler just like the other views, but it looks weird when scrolling down, if you have another strategy do share ^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109354/discussion-between-milannz-and-kurlicue).